# In R how to download an XML file that is zipped into a dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to download the PCR_LMP prices form the CIASO.

But everything I'm doing seems to not work. I would be happy to download them csv files as well to load in into the dataframe as well but I can't put together their url to get the API to return a csv file.

Any recommendations on how to download this data with R?

[Documentation to the API](http://www.caiso.com/Documents/OASIS-InterfaceSpecification_v5_1_1Clean_Fall2017Release.pdf)

To see examples of the xml files supplied.

http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20220919T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20220919T08:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&grp_type=ALL_APNODES

http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20220919T00:00-0000&enddatetime=20220919T08:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=LAPLMG1_7_B2

http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20220919T00:00-0000&enddatetime=20220919T08:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=GONDER_LNODEN1

Example of code I tried:

```
# Load required package
library(xml2)

# Set the path to the XML file
xml_file <- "E:/20130919_20130919_PRC_LMP_DAM_20230506_18_55_53_v1.xml"

# Read the XML file into an XML document object
xml_doc <- read_xml(xml_file)

# Print the XML document object
print(xml_doc)
```

Comment: What does the XML look like? What URL API did you attempt? XML path in your post points to a local disk path. You can parse the XML content into data frame. See the countless R SO posts to do so. Also, docs indicate CSV format can be achieved with additional param, `&resultformat=6`, otherwise defaults to XML.

Comment: the $rsultformat=6 only works for files after x date. I have to read xml before that date.